# What does this product converges to?

Tags: limits, infinity, integer-partitions, infinite-product

Let $p\in[0,1]$.

I'm interested in computing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p^i)$$

Any thoughts?

---

EDIT:
As Kibble mentioned, this is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

Also from Kibble: a simple upper bound is reached by ending the product early.

> **Can we derive a lower bound for $\phi(q)$?**

Comment: This is known as the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), see also [q-Pockhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: Thanks @Kibble. Do you know a way to derive a simple upper and lower bounds for it?

Comment: Should p be raised to the power i or n?

Comment: @K.Miller - $i$, corrected, thanks !

Comment: You get an upper bound comes by truncating the product after $k$ terms. So for example $\phi(p) < (1-p)(1-p^2) = 1-p-p^2+p^3$